# Convert ASP classic variable which contains a date to another date format

Tags: asp-classic

I have a varible that contains a date in the format of mm/dd/yy an I want to change that format to dd/mm/yy

I'm attempting to use the below code to do that:

```
<%
d= response.write con("date")
if IsDate(d) then
document.write(CDate(d))
%>
<tr>
    <td><%=con("location")%></td>
    <td><%=con("state")%></td>
    <td><%=con("date")%></td>
</tr>
```

Am I going about the wrong way or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well you have a few things wrong in your above code:

You can't use `response.write` like that -- you use that to write content to the page.  Change that line to:

```
d=con("date") & ""
```

I prefer appending blanks to remove potential null issues with classic ASP.

Then to convert that from mm/dd/yy to dd/mm/yy, you can try the following:

```
d = split(d,"/")
newd = d(1) & "/" & d(0) & "/" & d(2)
```

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: Is "d" a special variable? or is that the variable I use to get the new date format?

Comment: I was using your "d" variable in your example above -- it's just a local variable on your ASP page. Make sense?